# GRE practice: Total internal reflection question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, reflection

[image]

Hi, I am having a lot of troubling figuring out how to solve this problem. 
Equations: Snell's law leads to a total internal reflection equation $$\theta_c = \sin^{-1}(1/n).$$
This angle corresponds to the ray inside the fiber incident on the top side. With angles greater than this(up to some limit) it will totally internal reflect. 
Another equation I can get is for the free-space -> fiber interface in the beginning.
$$\begin{equation}\theta = \sin^{-1}(n\sin(\theta_1)) \\ \implies \theta_1 = \pi/2-\theta_c\end{equation}.$$ 
Combining these gives an ugly equation that doesn't make sense since the argument to one of the $\arcsin$ is imaginary. 
The answer is the last one. It just bugs me that I can't figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: Note that \sin exists inside the math environment.

Comment: Your picture is broken. It is highly recommended to upload pictures using the [built-in SE functionality.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post).

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Completely disagree with my answer being deleted, as well as this question being put on hold. Thousands of students take the physics GRE every year and the best way to study is to work on past test problems. Thus, having this question up, as well as a full solution is completely consistent with the site being "useful to the broader community, and to future users."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elimination by the use of limit analysis is probably the best way to do it on the actual test, but here's the full solution:

Let $\theta'$ by the angle that light enters the cable. By Snell's law this is $$\text{sin}(\theta') = \frac{1}{n}\text{sin}(\theta).$$ When it hits the interface the next time, you want total internal reflection, i.e the refracted angle $\theta''$ should have $\text{sin}(\theta'') > 1.$ Again by Snell's law and some trig, $$\text{sin}(\theta'') = n \,\text{sin} (90 - \theta) = n\, \text{cos}(\theta') = n\sqrt{1- \text{sin}^2(\theta')} = n\sqrt{1-\frac{\text{sin}^2(\theta)}{n^2}}, $$ which we want to be greater than 1. Manipulating the inequality gives $$\theta < \text{sin}^{-1}(\sqrt{n^2 -1}).$$

Answer (score 3):

It seems like this GRE question can be solved by the process of elimination. Maybe that's intended? Maybe they want to see you apply some intuition/insight rather than just crank through equations?

First, I think that it's apparent that for any n>1 that there will always be total internal reflection and the light will stay within the fiber if the entrance angle θ is sufficiently small and close to zero, right? So we can then eliminate answers (a), (c), and (e), which all assert that, on the contrary, that the entrance angle has to be larger than some minimum angle. That leaves answers (b) and (d) as possible answers. Answer (d) doesn't make sense because for n>1 the argument of the arcsine function is greater than 1, and that doesn't correspond to any real angle. That leaves answer (b), which appears to be a plausible answer: For an index of refraction n that is just slightly larger than 1, the entrance angle θ will be very small and close to zero. As n gets larger, the entrance angle also gets larger.